# How to create via API reference plane like Bottom Plane in SolidWorks

Tags: c#, solidworks, solidworksapi

I need to create a reference plane in SolidWorks via API. The plane should be the same as Bottom Plane, or Top Plane with inverted Normal.
I know how to make it by 3 points:

```
swModel.Insert3DSketch2(true);
var swSketchPt1 = swModel.CreatePoint2(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) as SketchPoint;
var swSketchPt2 = swModel.CreatePoint2(0.0, 0.0, -0.01) as SketchPoint;
var swSketchPt3 = swModel.CreatePoint2(-0.01, 0.0, 0.0) as SketchPoint;
swModel.Insert3DSketch2(true);
swModel.ClearSelection2(true);

swSketchPt1.Select(true);
swSketchPt2.Select(true);
swSketchPt3.Select(true);

var pl1 = swModel.CreatePlaneThru3Points3(true) as RefPlane;
```

But I hope there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Does this code work?

Comment: Yes, it works like a magic). But it's only a part of the script that explains the idea)

Comment: Generally, working code is only reviewed at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

In this case, a plane is made up of points. I'm not sure if there is any other way. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The problem is that CreatePlaneThru3Points3 is obsolete, but the new API IFeatureManager::InsertRefPlane doesn't allow me to create Bottom Plane.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a way but it's not pretty.

Insert your ref plane as normal using [FeatureManager.InsertRefPlane](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IFeatureManager%7EInsertRefPlane.html)

To flip normal we can use [SldWorks.RunCommand](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISldWorks%7ERunCommand.html) with
a value of [(3113) swCommands_RefPlane_Flip_Normal](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/swcommands/SolidWorks.Interop.swcommands%7ESolidWorks.Interop.swcommands.swCommands_e.html).

We still have to reverse the direction.

This can be done by modifying the [ReversedReferenceDirection](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IRefPlaneFeatureData%7EReversedReferenceDirection.html) property of the [RefPlaneFeatureData](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IRefPlaneFeatureData_members.html).

see full example below

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    Dim Offset As Double
    Offset = InputBox("Offset in mm", "Offset", 600)
    
    Offset = Offset / 1000
    
    Dim swFeature As SldWorks.Feature
    
    Rem For Assemblies
    Rem Dim swAssem As SldWorks.AssemblyDoc
    Rem Set swAssem = swModel
    Rem Set swFeature = swAssem.FeatureByName("Top Plane")
    
    Rem For Parts
    Dim swPart As SldWorks.PartDoc
    Set swPart = swModel
    Set swFeature = swPart.FeatureByName("Top Plane")
    
    swFeature.Select2 False, 0
    Set swFeature = swModel.FeatureManager.InsertRefPlane(swRefPlaneReferenceConstraint_Distance, Offset, 0, 0#, 0, 0#)
    swFeature.Name = "Bottom Plane"
    
    swFeature.Select2 False, 0
    swApp.RunCommand swCommands_RefPlane_Flip_Normal, ""
    
    Dim swRefPlaneFeatureData As SldWorks.RefPlaneFeatureData
    Set swRefPlaneFeatureData = swFeature.GetDefinition
    
    swRefPlaneFeatureData.ReversedReferenceDirection(swRefPlaneReference_First) = True
    swFeature.ModifyDefinition swRefPlaneFeatureData, swModel, Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `CreatePlaneThru3Points3` Method (IModelDoc2) is Obsolete. Superseded by `IFeatureManager::InsertRefPlane`.

SOURCE: [https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IModelDoc2~CreatePlaneThru3Points3.html](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IModelDoc2%7ECreatePlaneThru3Points3.html)

Here is the example they give for the new method:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Verify that the specified part exists.
// 2. Open the Immediate window.
//
// Postconditions:
// 1. Creates a constraint-based reference plane.
// 2. Examine the Immediate window.
//
// NOTE: Because the part is used elsewhere, do not
// save changes.
//-----------------------------------------------------------
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.swconst;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace InsertRefPlaneFeatureManagerCSharp.csproj

{

    public partial class SolidWorksMacro

    {

        public void Main()

        {

            ModelDoc2 swModel = default(ModelDoc2);

            ModelDocExtension swModelDocExt = default(ModelDocExtension);

            FeatureManager swFeatureManager = default(FeatureManager);

            Feature swFeature = default(Feature);

            RefPlane swRefPlane = default(RefPlane);

            SelectionMgr swSelMgr = default(SelectionMgr);

            RefPlaneFeatureData swRefPlaneFeatureData = default(RefPlaneFeatureData);

            int fileerror = 0;

            int filewarning = 0;

            bool boolstatus = false;

            int planeType = 0;

 

            swApp.OpenDoc6("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\SOLIDWORKS\\SOLIDWORKS 2018\\samples\\tutorial\\api\\plate.sldprt", (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, (int)swOpenDocOptions_e.swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", ref fileerror, ref filewarning);

            swModel = (ModelDoc2)swApp.ActiveDoc;

            swModelDocExt = (ModelDocExtension)swModel.Extension;

            swFeatureManager = (FeatureManager)swModel.FeatureManager;

            swSelMgr = (SelectionMgr)swModel.SelectionManager;

 

            // Create a constraint-based reference plane

            boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "FACE", 0.028424218552, 0.07057725774359, 0, true, 0, null, 0);

            boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", 0.05976462601598, 0.0718389621656, 0.0001242036435087, true, 1, null, 0);

            swRefPlane = (RefPlane)swFeatureManager.InsertRefPlane(16, 0.7853981633975, 4, 0, 0, 0);

 

            // Get type of the just-created reference plane

            boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Plane1", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, false, 0, null, (int)swSelectOption_e.swSelectOptionDefault);

            swFeature = (Feature)swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1);

            swRefPlaneFeatureData = (RefPlaneFeatureData)swFeature.GetDefinition();

 

            planeType = swRefPlaneFeatureData.Type2;

            Debug.Print("Type of reference plane using IRefPlaneFeatureData::Type2: ");

            switch (planeType)

            {

                case 0:

                    Debug.Print(" Invalid");

                    break;

                case 1:

                    Debug.Print(" Undefined");

                    break;

                case 2:

                    Debug.Print(" Line Point");

                    break;

                case 3:

                    Debug.Print(" Three Points");

                    break;

                case 4:

                    Debug.Print(" Line Line");

                    break;

                case 5:

                    Debug.Print(" Distance");

                    break;

                case 6:

                    Debug.Print(" Parallel");

                    break;

                case 7:

                    Debug.Print(" Angle");

                    break;

                case 8:

                    Debug.Print(" Normal");

                    break;

                case 9:

                    Debug.Print(" On Surface");

                    break;

                case 10:

                    Debug.Print(" Standard");

                    break;

                case 11:

                    Debug.Print(" Constraint-based");

                    break;

            }

            Debug.Print("");

 

            planeType = swRefPlaneFeatureData.Type;

            Debug.Print("Type of reference plane using IRefPlaneFeatureData::Type: ");

            switch (planeType)

            {

                case 0:

                    Debug.Print(" Invalid");

                    break;

                case 1:

                    Debug.Print(" Undefined");

                    break;

                case 2:

                    Debug.Print(" Line Point");

                    break;

                case 3:

                    Debug.Print(" Three Points");

                    break;

                case 4:

                    Debug.Print(" Line Line");

                    break;

                case 5:

                    Debug.Print(" Distance");

                    break;

                case 6:

                    Debug.Print(" Parallel");

                    break;

                case 7:

                    Debug.Print(" Angle");

                    break;

                case 8:

                    Debug.Print(" Normal");

                    break;

                case 9:

                    Debug.Print(" On Surface");

                    break;

                case 10:

                    Debug.Print(" Standard");

                    break;

                case 11:

                    Debug.Print(" Constraint-based");

                    break;

            }

            Debug.Print("");

 

            swModel.ClearSelection2(true);

        }

 

        /// <summary>

        /// The SldWorks swApp variable is pre-assigned for you.

        /// </summary>

        public SldWorks swApp;

 

    }

}
```

SOURCE: https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/Insert_Reference_Plane_Example_CSharp.htm

Comment: Yes, you are right that CreatePlaneThru3Points3 is obsolete. But IFeatureManager::InsertRefPlane doesn't allow you to create a plane as Bottom Plane (Top plane with flipped normal). Via UI you can do it, but when you record a macro the flip option will not be present in code.

Comment: Have you looked at the mirror component example?

https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/mirror_components_ii_example_csharp.htm